# Ariza"l and Seer (Chozeh) of Lublin on Korach

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism, quotations, parshat-korach

[This](https://www.jewishideas.org/article/hasidic-psychological-readings-revelation-and-korah) fascinating article says:

> The Seer of Lublin said: “Were I alive at the time, I would have
> supported Korah” … Rabbi Yitzhak Luria Ashkenazi, the Ari, writes: “In
> the future, Korah will be shown to have been correct.”

Can anyone point to the sources of these two quotes? Thanks

Comment: Regarding the Ari, I bet either Shaar HaPesukim or the Shelah on parshas Korach will be helpful

Comment: The first quote might be found in his work, Divrei Emet. I am still looking for it, but there is a great chance, that it's there. See: https://www.sefaria.org/Divrei_Emet?tab=contents

Comment: I highly doubt the Ari actually said that.

Comment: See Shem mishmuel

Answer (score 1):

R. Elazar of Worms (aka the Roqeah) in his [Perush on the Siddur (Hershler ed., p. 125)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49925&st=&pgnum=147), wrote:

> צדי**ק** כתמ**ר** יפר**ח** סופי תיבות קרח, שיהא כקרח בעשרו, כשם שתמר
> פורח כך קרח לעתיד, שנאמר מוריד שאול ויעל, קרח ועדתו יעלה. בחצרות
> אלקינו יפריחו שהמתים יפרחו בעזרה

That Psalm 92:13 "The righteous bloom like a date-palm" contains an allusion to Qorah (the last letter of each word spells his name) and supports the position of R. Eliezer (Sanhedrin 108a), that Qorah and his company will arise to the World to Come.

R. Isaac Luria did not actually commit much to writing. So any reference to his writings would rather be to those of his students. R. Haim Vital (one of his foremost disciples) wrote ([Peri Es Haim](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/vital/pri_ec_chajim.htm), towards the end of Sha'ar Hanhagath ha-Limud):

> על הגיתית לבני קרח, מה ידידות משכנותיך...והם אמרוהו על עצמם, שנתבצר
> להם מקום בגיהנם...ויצאו משם לשורר במקדש וגם אביהם יזכה לעתיד. והרמז
> בס"ת, צדי**ק**" כתמ**ר**" יפר**ח**", סופי תיבות, הוא קרח כנודע

Using the same סופי תיבות of Psalm 92:13 that the Roqeah mentioned, he sees it as containing an allusion to Qorah meriting a place in the future Temple.

R. Yaaqov Yishaq Horowitz (the Hozeh of Lublin) descended from the sons of Qorah (תולדות משפחת הורוויץ) and is [reputed](https://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?cat_id=4&topic_id=1446906&forum_id=771) to have referred to him as די הייליגער זיידע קרח (in Yiddish "the holy grandfather Qorah"). Hasidic sources (Sefer Liqutim, Bene Yisaskhar, et al) greatly expand upon this theme of Qorah's return and stature, the Divrei Yoel even went so far as to say the Qorah would be the Kohen Gadol (Shelah, p. 346).